# How do I get a list of all the roles my discord bot has?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get a list of all the roles my bot has from top to bottom so I can get the highest role's color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by the "highest role's color", also your post is missing your code.

One way to get the roles the bot has in the guild (via a command) is to  get the guild member object and then loop the role objects for that member.

Try this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def list_roles(ctx):
    bot_member = ctx.guild.get_member(bot.user.id)
    for bot_role in bot_member.roles:
        print(f'guild role {bot_role} color {bot_role.color}')
```

Console output:

```
guild role @everyone color #000000
guild role masterbot color #2ecc71
guild role winnerPicker color #e67e22
guild role gabAdmin color #ad1457
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a loop in all roles like this using [Guild.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)

```py
@bot.command()
async def get_roles(ctx):
    all_roles = []
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        all_roles.append(role.name)
    all_roles.reverse()# to make it higher first 
    print(all_roles)
```

Comment: This prints out a list of all the roles on the server. How would I print out just the roles the bot has?

Answer (score 0):

you can do with `.me` in a guild

#### getting the list:

```py
Guild = THE GUILD YOU WANT TO GET THE ROLES

BotMember = GUILD.members.me

for role in BotMember.roles:

print(f'Role: {role.name} Color: {role.color}')
```

console log:

```
Role: @everyone Color: #000000

Role: BaldeGuy Color: #2ecc71

Role: Lorrita Color: #e67e22

Role: Moderator Color: #ad1457
```

#### getting the highest role:

```py
Guild = THE GUILD YOU WANT TO GET THE ROLES

BotMember = GUILD.members.me

HighestRole = BotMember.roles.highest.name

print(f'Highest role: {HighestRole}')
```

console.log:

```
Highest role: {Moderator}
```